# How to remove Brush Size limit in sculpting

Tags: modeling, interface, sculpting

In *Sculpt Mode*, the brush size is limited to 500 px which is good in normal monitors, but is not good in 8k monitor. It looks like a little brush in 500 px size, and I need to change the size by typing number which isn't  intuitive. How could I remove the lock, and let it go higher when pressing the <kbd>F</kbd> key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you can't unlock the brush size limit in *Sculpt Mode* without changing the source code of Blender by yourself, because the feature of unlocking this limit is still under development.

In the year 2022 January, [Joe Eagar was about to add this feature](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/95114). However, after one year and a half, no further progress was reported. And now, Joe Eagar is no longer working for Blender development. He probably resigned.

I recommend you to contact Blender developers to push and realize this feature by commenting [here](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/95114).

Comment: i mean i actually can go above 500 pixels by typing the number ....

Answer (score 1):

In sculpt mode, under the Brush menu, switch the radius unit from View (measured in pixels) to Scene (measured in scene units).

[image]

Comment: although im pretty much agreed that the current answer would be scene units currently but after reading "blender lake" answer it was hard for me to choose the true answer cause logically the true answer is that blender isn't capable of doing such thing currently , BUT your answer helped me alot didn't considered that one